# Why is a timezone aware field timezone naive in postgres

Tags: elixir, ecto

I'm adding a utc timezone aware column to my scheme. However in my database the column typed as timestamp(0) with out zone.

What did I do wrong? 
My scheme looks like this:

```
defmodule Transaction do
    use Ecto.Schema
    import Ecto.Changeset

    schema "transaction" do
      field :platform_transaction_at, :utc_datetime
    end
end
```

My migration file looks like

```
defmodule Transaction.Migrations.AddPlatformTransactionDatetime do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    alter table(:transaction) do
      add :platform_transaction_at, :utc_datetime
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL does not have a data type for storing a timestamp with timezone. See [this elixir forum thread](https://elixirforum.com/t/difference-in-between-utc-datetime-and-naive-datetime-in-ecto/12551/2) for more discussion. You might object that there does indeed exist a type called "timestamp with timezone", but an answer in that thread further explains:

> There is the confusingly named timestamp with timezone but all it does is convert your input timestamp to UTC and convert it back to whatever your DB connection’s timezone is when reading (so for most cases it’s useless). It does not even store the offset/timezone. So you need to do that yourself somehow.

Both `:utc_datetime` and `:naive_datetime` in Ecto migrations create the same type in Postgres: `timestamp without time zone` http://www.creativedeletion.com/2019/06/17/utc-timestamps-in-ecto.html

The good news is that you are already storing your timestamps correctly by specifying `:utc_datetime` in your schema and migration, because even though it becomes a `timestamp without timezone`, "all timezone-aware dates and times are stored internally in UTC." https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-TIMEZONES

Comment: Postgresql does store the offset for timestamp with timezones. You can see it when querying from psql. And as for being "useless", it seems like a very biased and debatable opinion.

Comment: `psql` may be injecting that timezone information; as described, `timestamp with timezone` uses the timezone of the  *connection*, which may or may not be UTC.

Comment: See https://www.toolbox.com/tech/data-management/blogs/zone-of-misunderstanding-092811/ specifically "The difference that “with time zone” makes is that whenever a timestamp is stored, it is automatically converted from the user’s time zone (as defined in their PostgreSQL connection) to UTC.  When a user requests the timestamp back, it is converted from UTC to the user’s local time zone again.". Because it's connection-relative, you can easily see different behaviour on your dev and prod, or even between prods depending on server configuration.